# Problem in creating a separate function to read file in Hadoop Streaming

Tags: python, hadoop

I have problem in creating a separate function to read file in Hadoop Streaming.

mapper.py: `Works well (very inefficient)`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

def main():     
   for line in sys.stdin:
     line = line.strip() # each line contains only one word, 5+ million lines

     filename = "my_dict.txt" # contains 7+ million words
     f = open(filename,"r")
     for line1 in f: 
        line1 = line1.strip()
        if line1 == line:
           print  '%s\t%s' % (line1, 1) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My function to read file

mapper.py: `not working`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

def read_dict():
    listD=[]
    filename = "my_dict.txt"
    f = open(filename,"r")
    for line1 in f: 
       listD.append(line1.strip()) 
    return listD

def main():
   listDM = set(read_dict())    
   for line in sys.stdin:
     line = line.strip()

     for line1 in listDM: 
        if line1 == line:
           print  '%s\t%s' % (line1, 1) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My Error log:

```
hadoop_admin@gml-VirtualBox:/usr/local/hadoop$ sh myScripts/runHadoopStream.sh 
Deleted hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoop_admin/output
packageJobJar: [/var/www/HMS/my_dict.txt, /usr/local/hadoop/mapper.py, /usr/local/hadoop/reducer.py, /tmp/hadoop-hadoop_admin/hadoop-unjar6634198925772314314/] [] /tmp/streamjob1880303974118879660.jar tmpDir=null
11/07/20 18:40:08 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2
11/07/20 18:40:08 INFO streaming.StreamJob: getLocalDirs(): [/tmp/hadoop-hadoop_admin/mapred/local]
11/07/20 18:40:08 INFO streaming.StreamJob: Running job: job_201107181559_0091
11/07/20 18:40:08 INFO streaming.StreamJob: To kill this job, run:
11/07/20 18:40:08 INFO streaming.StreamJob: /usr/local/hadoop/bin/../bin/hadoop job  -Dmapred.job.tracker=localhost:9001 -kill job_201107181559_0091
11/07/20 18:40:08 INFO streaming.StreamJob: Tracking URL: http://localhost:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201107181559_0091
11/07/20 18:40:09 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 0%  reduce 0%
11/07/20 18:40:41 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 1%  reduce 0%
11/07/20 18:40:47 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 0%  reduce 0%
11/07/20 18:41:05 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 1%  reduce 0%
11/07/20 18:41:08 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 0%  reduce 0%
11/07/20 18:41:26 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 1%  reduce 0%
11/07/20 18:41:29 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 0%  reduce 0%
11/07/20 18:41:48 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 1%  reduce 0%
11/07/20 18:41:51 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 0%  reduce 0%
11/07/20 18:41:57 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 100%  reduce 100%
11/07/20 18:41:57 INFO streaming.StreamJob: To kill this job, run:
11/07/20 18:41:57 INFO streaming.StreamJob: /usr/local/hadoop/bin/../bin/hadoop job  -Dmapred.job.tracker=localhost:9001 -kill job_201107181559_0091
11/07/20 18:41:57 INFO streaming.StreamJob: Tracking URL: http://localhost:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201107181559_0091
11/07/20 18:41:57 ERROR streaming.StreamJob: Job not Successful!
11/07/20 18:41:57 INFO streaming.StreamJob: killJob...
Streaming Job Failed!
```

Shell script used to run Hadoop Streaming:

```
bin/hadoop dfs -rmr output
bin/hadoop jar contrib/streaming/hadoop-*-streaming.jar  -file  /var/www/HMS/my_dict.txt  -file /usr/local/hadoop/mapper.py -mapper /usr/local/hadoop/mapper.py -file /usr/local/hadoop/reducer.py -reducer /usr/local/hadoop/reducer.py -input input/ -output output/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simplified script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

def main():
    filename = "my_dict.txt"
    listfile = open(filename)
    # doesn't create an itermediate list
    listDM = set(line.strip() for line in listfile)
    # less Pythonic but significantly faster
    # still doesn't create an intermediate list
    # listDM = set(imap(str.strip, listfile))
    listfile.close()  
    for line in sys.stdin:
        line = line.strip()
        if line in listDM:
            print  '%s\t%d' % (line, 1) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you use the faster commented out alternative, you need to `from itertools import imap`.